# Trying to make a tabbed browser

Tags: macos, cocoa, webview, tabview

I'm having a problem with cocoa, when I run the app the tabs get added as expected, but all the web views take the same string from the url field.

Basically, if I go to google on one tab, it goes to google on all of them.

Is there any way to make only the web view on the selected tab respond, and not on the others?

Here is the code:

```
- (IBAction)newTab:(id)sender {
NSTabViewItem *item = [NSTabViewItem new];
[item setView:_webView];
[item setLabel:@"New Tab"];
[_tabView addTabViewItem:item];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're creating a new tab and then moving your WebView to it. To create a new web view for each tab, you have some options but one is to use NSViewController:

1. If you create the web view in the same xib as the tab view, move it to a separate xib. Change the class of the owner of that xib to NSViewController.
2. When adding a new tab in your code, load the xib (assuming it is named WebView.xib):

```
- (IBAction) newTab: (id) sender
{
    NSTabViewItem *item = [[NSTabViewItem alloc] init];
    NSViewController *viewController =
        [[NSViewController alloc] initWithNibName: @"WebView" bundle: nil];
    WebView *webView = [viewController view];
    [item setView: webView];

    [_tabView addTabViewItem: item];
    [_webViewControllers addObject: viewController]; // Store the view controller, remove when the user closes the tab.
}
```

Here's a tutorial on view controllers: http://comelearncocoawithme.blogspot.fi/2011/07/nsviewcontrollers.html

Comment: isn't uiwebview for iOS though?

Comment: @tsnorn by any chance, could you send an Xcode project my way, I have no idea how to implement it

Comment: Fixed. I'll try to come up with something.

Comment: Here you go. First add a new tab and use “http://” in front of URLs.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/hr71754s917c56p/TabbedBrowser.zip

Comment: If someone still needs the file, here's a new link:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/pif2uqv8fy524u3/TabbedBrowser.zip